# How to run PUTTY and skip dialog?

Tags: asp.net, web, putty, windows-command-prompt, runas

I have a web application that contains a command to start an EXE

```
Process.Start("MyApp.exe")
```

This app will then run `putty.exe` and will `SendKeys` to emulate keystrokes to the application.

The app works fine if I start under my username, or even if I run using `runas /user:anyother_user`.

The problem is, when `MyApp.exe` starts `putty.exe` (which is what should happen when someone opens a certain web page), I can see that the app is started, and a process is created for both `MyApp.EXE` and `putty.exe`. However, nothing seems to be visible to me or any user. Mainly because the application is started under `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`. 
I can tell that none of the keystrokes that `MyApp` is sending, are reaching putty.

I suspect that it is due to `putty` launching a dialog box for the first time it runs under a user (prompting to establish secure connection, etc..).

My questions are:

1. Can I somehow tell putty to avoid these dialog boxes?
2. Can I tell `ntauthority\networkservice` to dismiss the dialogbox raised by putty?
3. Can I view the `putty` window launched by `network service`? so that I may dismiss it myself and then it will no longer appear again?
4. Can I run `putty` as any other user (without having to store any passwords, for security reasons)?

Any answer to these questions will help me achieve my goal.

Comment: Can I ask what your use-case is? This sounds like something that would be better served by e.g. https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET rather than trying to pupetteer putty

Comment: @frymaster I am trying to send a sequence of commands to a remote server to stop and start a certain service. Putty is used because it supports SSH. Is there a .NET library reference I can add to my project so that I can do the commands from within the web application?

Comment: @frymaster I looked at the link you proposed, I don't know how can I make use of any of the files up there. I was expecting to find a COM library or a class file that will allow me to create SSH connections. I am a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box dialog seems to be the acceptation of the hostkey of the remote server. Putty asks to confirm the hostkey to store this key in the registry of the user who wants to connect to him. If you want to bypass this dialog, you can force the use of a specified hostkey with the `-hostkey` option.

Moreover, you can explain to putty to use a serie of commands stored in a text file with the `-m` option.

All these options are explained here : [putty](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter3.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `-m` I will read more about it. But I could not find information about `-hostfile`. Are you sure about that?

Comment: -hostkey not hosfile :`3.8.3.20 -hostkey: manually specify an expected host key

This option overrides PuTTY's normal SSH host key caching policy by telling it exactly what host key to expect, which can be useful if the normal automatic host key store in the Registry is unavailable. The argument to this option should be either a host key fingerprint, or an SSH-2 public key blob. See section 4.19.3 for more information.

You can specify this option more than once if you want to configure more than one key to be accepted. `

Comment: I tried running `putty -hostkey` but got a message: `Unknown option -hostkey`

Comment: You must use the 0.67 version. This option is not in the 0.62 version for example.